# Doing Accuracy Assessment using test data from shapefile in ENVI?

Tags: classification, envi, accuracy, confusion-matrix

ENVI 5.2.1. From a .tiff image (4 bands) I created a Supervised Classification Maximum Likelihood .dat file. Now I want to perform an Accuracy Assessment using test data from a shapefile. I've tried using the tool -> Confusion Matrix Using Ground Truth ROIs. When the Classification Input File window appears, I select my MaxlikeSupervised.dat file and I get an error "There are no available ROIs or EVFs associated with this input file"

Do I have to create and ROI file?

How do I do this?

Do I need to use Ground Truth image and how do I get this?

All the files I have is that one image file which I created a supervised classification .dat file and I have test data points from a shapefile to match it up to the .dat file.

Answer (score 1):

You can/must convert your .shp file to ROI in ENVI. Go to vector > convert vector to ROI and select your shapefiles.

Check this video for converting to ROI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukrgGUkxJlU
from 7:20